# Максимальная длина сообщения и компоненты Indy

Tags: delphi, indy

Всем привет,
Пытаюсь отправить сообщение с использованием `TIdMessage`. 
У меня есть HTML-страница в качестве шаблона и какой-то большой текст, который нужно вставить в шаблон (в специальном месте, который был отмечен как ##text##). После слияния шаблона и текста, я получаю тело моего нового сообщения. Потом я отправляю это сообщение (используйте `TIdMessage` и `TIdSMTP`), но в результате сообщение содержит только вторую часть текста. Текст имеет больше 40,000 символов. Когда я посылаю сообщение без HTML шаблона (только большой текст) все ок.

Как я могу установить длину сообщения?

Я ставил

```
FIdMessage.ContentTransferEncoding := 'quoted-printable' and FIdSMTP.MsgLineLength := MAXWORD
```

но это не помогло (((

Заранее спасибо.
Вот мой код:

```
var
  FSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  FIdMessage: TIdMessage;
  idx: integer;
  i: Integer;
  FIdText: TIdText;
begin
  FSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create( nil );
  FIdMessage := TIdMessage.Create( nil );
  try
    try
      FIdMessage.ExtraHeaders.Clear;
      FIdMessage.MessageParts.Clear;

      // Attachments
      for idx := 0 to Attachments.Count - 1 do
        TIdAttachment.Create( FIdMessage.MessageParts,
          TEmailAttachment( Attachments.Items[ idx ] ).FLocalTemplateName );


      FIdMessage.From.Text := FFrom;
      FIdMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := FTo;
      FIdMessage.Subject := FSubject;
      if (FHtmlTemplateFilePath <> '') then
      begin
        FIdMessage.ContentType := 'multiparts/related; type="text/html"';
        AddAttachements(FIdMessage);  // procedure that added Attachments

        FIdText := TIdText.Create(FIdMessage.MessageParts, nil);
        FIdText.Body.Text := 'Please view a html version of this email';
        FIdText.ContentType := 'text/plain';


        FIdText := TIdText.Create(FIdMessage.MessageParts, nil);
        FIdText.Body.Text := FBody;
        FIdText.ContentType := 'text/html';

      end
      else
      begin
        FIdMessage.Body.Text := FBody;
      end;    

      FIdMessage.CCList.Clear;
      FIdMessage.ReceiptRecipient.Text := '';

      FSMTP.AuthenticationType := FSMTPAuthenticationType;
      FSMTP.UserID := FSMTPUserID;
      FSMTP.Password := FSMTPPassword;
      FSMTP.Host := FSMTPHost;
      FSMTP.Port := FSMTPPort;
      FSMTP.MsgLineLength := MAXWORD;

      RepeatRetryCount := FSMTPRepeatRetryCount;
      FSMTP.Connect;
       try
            FSMTP.Send( FIdMessage );
       finally
            FSMTP.Disconnect;
       end;
     except
       end;
  finally
    FSMTP.Free;
    FIdMessage.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Никогда так не делайте:    `except   end;`

Comment: ну это пока тестовая версия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем, я кажется нашел решение. 
Проблема была с `CR` `LF`. 
Перед тем как запускалась моя процедура (см. выше) для отправки сообщения я вставлял большой текст, вместо ##text## в HTML-шаблон. 
Сначала я заменил все `CR` `LF` на `<br>` в **моем тексте**, а затем я заменил ##text## в шаблоне на **мой текст**. (**мой текст** - большой текст)

В результате я получил тело сообщения перед отправкой:

```
<html>
....
<body>
some large text <br> in one line. This text have more 40,000 characrets.....
</body>
</html>
```

Само сообщение:

> ine. This text have more 40,000 characrets

Но, когда я оставил `CR` `LF` и добавил к ним тег `<br>`, то я получил тело:

```
<html>
....
  <body>
    some large text <br> 
    in one line. This text have more 40,000 characrets.....
  </body>
</html>
```

И сообщение:

> some large text in one line. This text have more 40,000
>   characrets.....

Значить в этом случае, если весь текст в одной строке тогда ообщение обрезаеться, а если текст в HTML в нескольких линиях тогда все в порядке

Comment: Но я не понимаю, почему проблема с текстом, который находится в одной строке? Есть ли ограничения по длине строк в HTML?

Answer (score 0):

В этом участке кода Вы что-то делаете не так:

```
FIdText := TIdText.Create(FIdMessage.MessageParts, nil); // новый объект класса TIdText
FIdText.Body.Text := 'Please view a html version of this email';
FIdText.ContentType := 'text/plain';

// еще один новый объект класса TIdText затирает собой объект,
// созданный 3-мя строчками выше + утечка памяти размером с TIdText.
FIdText := TIdText.Create(FIdMessage.MessageParts, nil);
```

Comment: там все ок. `TIdText.Create` запускает `TIdMessagePart.Create` и создает MessagePart для моего FIdMessage. Работает вроде правильно. В smpt4dev приходит 2 части только вторая body обрезана: `FIdText.Body.Text := FBody;`

Comment: FIdMessage.SaveToFile перед отправкой сохраняет весь текст